# Linear spaces - polynomial basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

1) In a vector space $V$ of all real polynomials of third degree or less find basis $B$ such that for arbitrary polynomial $p \in V$ the following applies:
$[p]_B = \begin{pmatrix} p'(0)\\p'(1)\\p(0)\\p(0)\end{pmatrix}$ where $p'$ is the derivative of the polynomial $p$.

I thought that normally, for the polynomials of third or less degree we would have this linear span:
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\\0\\0 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 0\\1\\0\\0 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\1\\0 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\0\\1 \end{pmatrix}.$$
And the polynomial $ax^3 + bx^2+ cx + d$ would be represented by $$\begin{pmatrix} d\\c\\b\\a \end{pmatrix}.$$

The problem is asking me to define a basis such that the coeficient of $p$ in our first basis will always be the derivation of $p$ in 0, the coeficient in second basis the derivation of $p$ in 1 etc.

So we should for get:

$p'(0): c$

$p'(1): 3a^2+2b+c$

$p(0): d $

$p(1):  a^3+b^2+c+d$

With that how can I now write the final solution? What combination gives me the result?

Thank you.

Comment: You’ve got a typo at the top: $p(0)$ for the last coordinate, but you have $p(1)$ later, which makes more sense.

Comment: Also, $p'(0)\ne d$.

Comment: fixed it, just a typo

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: What do the standard basis vectors look like in this new basis?

Comment: Hmm.. I understand that if you have some polynomial, e.g. $p(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^3+(-\frac{3}{2})x^2+1$ and you want to write that using the standard basis $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$ you get $p(x)=1\cdot1+0\cdot x+\left(-\frac32\right)x^2+\frac12x^3\;$ with coeficients $1,0,-\frac32$ and $\frac12$ but I dont have a polynomial like that.. I have some new basis with four elements.

Comment: @user297103 You’re kind of approaching the problem backwards. Essentially, what you’re being asked to do is find the matrix that corresponds to a change-of-basis transformation. For _any_ linear transformation, the columns of its matrix are the images of the basis vectors.

Answer (score 0):

It looks quite simple: write an arbitary polynomial $p$ as a linear combination of 4 polynomials where the scalars are given in terms of the coefficients of $p$: $p = a_0 p_1 + a_1 p_2 + \dots$.

Note that this is equation system of equations. For each of these equations you can compare the coefficients of $a_j$ - so you get 4 equations for 4 parameters: the $j$-th coefficients for $p_1, \dots, p_4$.

Comment: Not sure I understand... What should I do with the result I got? I have some vector with four elements, now should I use that to rewrite some arbitrary polynomial as a linear combination?

Comment: Or take the arbitrary polynomial $ax^3 + bx^2+ cx + d$ as LHS of our equation, and the expression for p'(0), etc.. as our RHS? And have system of four equations?